# Dealing with latency in a multiplayer game

Tags: algorithm, networking, multiplayer, latency

What is the best way to deal with network latency in a synchronized multiplayer game? Could you advise me on an algorithm or method to use?

Thank you.

Comment: Might be more appropriate on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These posts [(1)](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/09/synchronous-rts-engines-and-a-tale-of-desyncs/) [(2)](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/24/synchronous-rts-engines-2-sync-harder/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods.

- Brute-force method (sending position of every character for each 1/30 second): good for first trial but works well only for high performance network environments
- [Dead reckoning](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamasutra.com%2Fview%2Ffeature%2F131638%2Fdead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php&ei=fYRCVPbROaHwmAWciIDoBw&usg=AFQjCNHamOk4ByKorXCoiDk1BPssAuTh9Q&sig2=0sVV_OLgOdASOMxzuXyv6Q&bvm=bv.77648437,d.dGY&cad=rjt): widely used methods for action or RPG games
- [Lockstep synchronization](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131503/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php): widely used methods for real-time simulation games